# adding the same key twice in the Map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I was doing research on `Map`s and I discovered that if I add the same key twice deliberately then the size of the Map remains the same. What's the technical reason behind this?

```
 Map map=new HashMap();//HashMap key random order.
         map.put("Amit","Java");
         map.put("Amit","Java");
```

Code for retrieving...

```
System.out.println("There are "+map.size()+" elements in the map.");
         System.out.println("Content of Map are...");
         Set s=map.entrySet();
         Iterator itr=s.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext())
         {
             Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
             System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+m.getValue()+"\t"+ m.hashCode());
          }
```

The result that I get:

```
There are 1 elements in the map.
Content of Map are...
Amit    Java    3943477
```

Comment: Thats the whole point of Maps.

Answer (score 27):

Because [Map's contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is that keys must be unique. So if you associate a new value to an existing key, it will override the value of the existing entry, not create a new entry:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

You can also check [Map#put() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) (emphasis mine):

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). **If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.** (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)

Comment: @assylias..Thanks is this rule apply to every forms of map whether it is tree map etc..!!

Comment: If this rule doesn't apply, then it's not a valid `Map` implementation.  So, yes.

Comment: @user1579492 every class that implements map is supposed to comply with the contract defined in the interface. All the map implementations in the JDK do comply with Map's contract.

Comment: Since its in Map's contract its has to apply to everything implementing a Map otherwise it is breaks the contract.

Comment: @assylias could you also please tell me how to generate the javadoc for this in eciplse or through command line that will be a great help..!

Comment: @user1579492 What do you mean "generate the javadoc for this"?

Comment: I want to generate the javadoc so that I can study the structure and classes of map in detail..!!

Comment: @user1579492 The javadoc is online. It's the first link in my post. The javadoc also lists all implementing classes at the very top..

Answer (score 2):

A standard Java Map can only have one value per key. Note that that value *could* be a collection, and thus you can effectively store multiple values per key.

If you want multiple identical keys in a map, various solutions exist. See the Guava [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the new key is same as any of the existing keys, then the value in the map is overwritten.